# Запуск JavaScript кода

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста есть ли способы запускать JS код после выполнения всех остальных скриптов?
В частности поясню суть подробнее:
на странице есть скрипт добавления карты, необходимо выполнять код после того как этот скрипт отработал и карта подгружена и отрисована.
Пробовал через `window.onload` эффект нулевой. Ничего лучше не придумал как поставить таймаут.

Comment: все зависит от самого скрипта. что за карта?

Comment: @Grundy, карта грузится yandex map  javascript - ом

Comment: у нее есть метод load в api

Comment: @Grundy, она добавляется этой строкой: <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?sid=JEGJKOdPm1vYtmZ-YqyyEk4L7jnopmWs&width=700&height=350"></script>  как я могу использовать этот метод в своем файле?

Comment: Может есть способы смотреть выполнились ли все аякс запросы на странице?

Comment: только если кровавым способом пропатчить `XMLHttpRequest`. И это скорее всего не нужно. Если нужно выполнить код, когда карта будет готова - так и надо выполнять этот код по соответствующему событию

Comment: `ymaps.ready(init);` разве не подходит для этого?

Comment: можете листинг опубликовать?

Comment: @P.Fateev, судя по всему конструктор яндекса не предоставляет апи для работы с созданной картой